# How to manage multiple .properties files in Spring Boot for different deploying environments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application where in the `src/main/resources` directory I have multiple **.properties** files which I'm using something like this given below via code:

`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:properties/myfunctional.properties”)`

Currently, I'm able to achieve my work with this as it's a simple functionality.

But the thing is keeping all these **.properties** files in `src/main/resources` is not a good idea because of the following reasons:

- These **.properties** files will be part of the build and packaged  into a **.jar** file.
- I guess storing sensitive information like **apikey**, **token** in the codebase via properties is not a good practice.

So, I have few questions around this:

- How and where can I move all of my **.properties** files to an external server?
- How to roll out property changes during the deployment as these values are going to differ based on the environment like **dev**, **test**, **stage** & **prod**?

**Note:** Few of the techniques I have tried with **Spring Boot Config**, **Git Secret Variable** and so on. But again I'm not sure on how much secure these techniques are.

So, I'm looking for an answer which will cover broader aspects.

Comment: use Spring Cloud Config Server

Comment: Config Server is better in your case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve your requirements via **Spring Cloud Config Server** and **Client.**

Please refer to this doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/).

---

**Github Approach:**

Step-By-Step Process where a **Github** repo will be acting as a source for all external properties files containing confidential/sensitive data.

1. I have created and hosted all my `secrets-{env}.properties` files on my Github [repo](https://github.com/anishb266/secrets-repo) for testing and demonstration.

[image]

**secrets-dev.properties:**

```
secrets.api-key=<dev-api-key>
secrets.token=<dev-token>
```

**secrets-stage.properties:**

```
secrets.api-key=<stage-api-key>
secrets.token=<stage-token>
```

**secrets-test.properties:**

```
secrets.api-key=<test-api-key>
secrets.token=<test-token>
```

**secrets-prod.properties:**

```
secrets.api-key=<prod-api-key>
secrets.token=<prod-token>
```

2. You have to create and setup the Spring Boot Cloud Config Server (acting as an **external server**) which will take the responsibility of connecting to the Github external repository and provide the necessary way for the clients to get access to the properties files based on the environment.

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sb-externalize-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sb-externalize-config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/anishb266/secrets-repo
server.port=8081
```

**Key points to be noted:**

- You have to set `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/anishb266/secrets-repo` to connect to that repo.

Startup Class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class SbExternalizeConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbExternalizeConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

You have to use `@EnableConfigServer` to make it an external config server.

Now, I will be running the external config server on port `8081`.

**Output:**

Accessing one of the properties, i.e, **secrets-test.properties** like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/{application}/{env} 

application - secrets
env - test
```

[image]

**Config Server Log:**

[image]

3. You have to create and setup the Spring boot Cloud Config client which will connect to config server and get the properties value based on the environment.

Project Structure:

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sb-externalize-config-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sb-externalize-config-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8081
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=secrets
spring.profiles.active=test
```

**Key points to be noted here:**

- You have set the `spring.application.name` with the application name (here it's `secrets`) before `-{env}.properties` for looking up into config server. Otherwise, it won't work. Basically, it tries to find properties file via **name of the application**. By default, the name is `application` only. So, it will try to find **application-{env}.properties** by default.
- For testing, I'm keeping `spring.profiles.active=test` so that client will try to fetch the properties from **secrets-test.properties** via config server.
- You have set this `spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8081` for connecting to the external server.

**SecretsProperties:**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("secrets")
public class SecretsProperties {

    private String apiKey;

    private String token;

    public SecretsProperties(String apiKey, String token) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SecretsProperties [apiKey=" + apiKey + ", token=" + token + "]";
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

}
```

This class is to map the loaded properties.

Startup class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecretsProperties.class)
public class SbExternalizeConfigClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbExternalizeConfigClientApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

TestController for testing:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    private SecretsProperties properties;

    public TestController(SecretsProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @GetMapping("test-external-properties")
    public SecretsProperties testExternalProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Now, I'm running the client at 8080 with profiles `test`.

**Client Log:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Providing a part of the External Config server log to proof that client was able to pick the desired properties with **test** profile via config server with the application-name `secrets`:

```
2023-10-16T18:04:48.433+05:30  INFO 79167 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'file [/var/folders/yq/m5hjv94j18586b1gzwzjg1tw0000gn/T/config-repo-5291131953887905898/secrets-test.properties]' via location 'file:/var/folders/yq/m5hjv94j18586b1gzwzjg1tw0000gn/T/config-repo-5291131953887905898/'
```

That's all.

---

**HashiCorp Vault Approach:**

If you are looking for a more secured and encrypted way of saving properties, then go for **HashiCorp Vault**.

**Note:** Vault acts as an external server for keeping secrets. So, you don't need to create an external server from scratch.

Read the Spring Boot docs [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/) on how to do it.

From Docs:

> Vault is a secrets management system allowing you to store sensitive
> data which is encrypted at rest. It’s ideal to store sensitive
> configuration details such as passwords, encryption keys, API keys.

Process is quite similar but there will some changes.

- First download Vault for [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/downloads).
- Extract it. There will be only one file `vault.sh`.
- Follow the installation process [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-dev-server).
- For demonstation purposes, I have used this command -> `./vault server --dev --dev-root-token-id="abc"` where I have taken an example token as `abc`. Please don't run like this in prod.
- Open another console and execute this command.

  ```
    export VAULT_TOKEN="abc"
    export VAULT_ADDR="http://127.0.0.1:8200"
  ```
- Enter the values to vault. **Format:**

  ```
    ./vault kv put secret/{application-name}/{env} key=value
  ```
- Example commands to put data into vault:

  ```
    ./vault kv put secret/secrets/test secrets.api-key=something secrets.token=something

    ./vault kv put secret/secrets/dev secrets.api-key=nothing secrets.token=nothing
  ```
- I will be using the same existing client project to demonstrate.

Add this dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>. 
</dependency>
```

You don't need this dependency below anymore:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Kindly remove this.

pom.xml will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sb-externalize-config-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sb-externalize-config-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Set **application.properties** with the below properties:

```
spring.application.name=secrets
spring.cloud.vault.token=abc
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.default-context=
spring.config.import=vault://secret/${spring.application.name}/${spring.profiles.active}
spring.profiles.active=test
```

**Points to be noted:**

- By default, the spring cloud starter vault picks and appends the `/application` as application name to lookup for the secrets from vault. To prevent this, we need to add `spring.cloud.vault.kv.default-context=` property.

The **TestController**, **SecretsProperties** and **SbExternalizeConfigClientApplication** remain the same.

**Output:**

I'm running the client for `test` profile.

[image]

**Note:** This was a very basic approach that I showed with Vault.

**Read docs for more info on how to do more advanced setup for Vault.**

Comment: @David I have updated my answer with Vault approach.

Comment: B sorry for late reply and thanks for answer +1 upvote. Yes I have gone through the spring cloud config. Here Like what is the point of using that as again we are keeping our properties in git only/. THis is conerning me. 

I am trying HashCorp  valut  approch, looking how to deployment on different servers and all. 

I'll update you. and coffee for sure. Thanks mate.

Comment: allow me couple of days. Local is up I am looking into the deployment on different server.

Comment: B What will be the cost in these cases any idea. Lets say I have to run my applications in these 4 servers (dev, test, stage and Prod) with atleast 100 secrest are there as of now in my properties.

Comment: @David Not sure on the costs part. I guess it should be faster and has support for distributed system. But I found one article which does the performance-benchmark on the vault. See this link -> https://medium.com/hashicorp-engineering/hashicorp-vault-performance-benchmark-13d0ea7b703f if this helps.

Comment: B one quick question : HashiCorp Vault Approach: can we do as a opensource. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @David What do you mean by `can we do as a opensource ` ? I didn't understand your point.

Comment: B Hasicrop have open source and enterprise ... so wann know this is what we are using is open-source right. I have created a vault but that is restricted to only 25 secrets

Comment: @David Yes you are right. I have used the open source one. Not the enterprise one.

Comment: B Thanks. so In this I can have store `x` number of secrets. I am not able to find any difference between enterprise and opensource so asked.

Comment: B yes there I have created and store my secret but this is cloud. not open sources. or not something which i can host

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255669/discussion-between-david-and-anish-b).

Answer (score 0):

### Question

1. how and where I can move my properties to external server.

every country developers have different tools in java , in china  we often use [nacos](https://nacos.io/en-us/docs/what-is-nacos.html) to storage sentsitively
which is a distributed naming and configuration center

2. How to roll out property changes during deployments because these values are different on different environment like Dev, Test, Stage and Production.

> Locally

In genernal ,we often name spring profiles as the type following

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-uat.properties
application-uat.properties
```

when different server environment  is required , we  add extra command before  we start up the jar . have a try with folowing command to  this

```bash
// the application shoule be your jar name
java -jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=dev application.jar
```

> Remote

basic there would be a config propertis  indeciate the properties config center host , some thing like (just example , not in real usage)

```
// you deploy tools  server ip
remote.config.host = http://192.168.2.1:8848   
// the env properties which you would like to active
remote.config.namespace = dev
```

please refer to  [nacos](https://nacos.io/en-us/docs/what-is-nacos.html) useage , i think there could be more helpful  knowledge for you scenario